# How to print the element in JSoup using Java

Tags: jsoup

I wrote a function in Java to fetch 10 links by their IDs from a given URL. The `href` tag IDs in the HTML code are written as: `id-1`, `id-2`, etc. I'm using JSoup library. My code is:

```
    public static void linkList(String URL)
       {
          Document doc=Jsoup.parse(URL);
          Element e;
          int eId=1;

              for(int x=1; x<=10; x++)
              {
                //element ids: id-1, id-2, etc.. 
                e = doc.getElementById("id-"+eId); 
               System.out.println(e); //print the link
               eId++; //increment the id to fetch the next
              }
       }
```

The output I get is always `null`. This is my first time to use JSoup and when I tried to ask in JSoup website, it guids me to Stack Overflow for any questions regarding JSoup.

Comment: I'm sure by using view source I searched about the tag and find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
String elementText = e.text();
```

Comment: After adding your line, it worked. BUT, For some reasons that I don't understand, when I replaced: "Document doc=Jsoup.parse(URL);" by: " File input = new File("file.txt")", then followed by:"document doc = Jsoup.parse(input,"UTF-8");" in addition to your line, it worked. i.e, it works when reading from text file but not when reading from URL directly, though, the id is the same in both cases.

Comment: (I know it's late but whatever) Well that's because you have to connect with the url. You use parse when you want to load a Document from a string. When you want to load a Document from url you do Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();